# jQuery in javascripts assets not firing

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

If I place this code inside the erb view it works perfectly

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.disabled-course').click(function() {
    $('#alert').html(
      '<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible">' +
      '  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>' +
      '  <h4><i class="icon fa fa-warning"></i>¡Alerta!</h4>' +
      '  Los cursos en vivo solo están disponibles para usuarios premium' +
      '</div>'
    );
  })
</script>
```

However when I place the same code (except the script tags) inside it's own file in the assets/javascripts folder it stops working.
I also don't get unicode characters to show properly (I get 'Ã¡' instead of 'á')

This is how the js file generated by rails looks like:

```
$('.disabled-course').click(function() {
  $('#alert').html(
    '<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible">' +
    '  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">Ã—</button>' +
    '  <h4><i class="icon fa fa-warning"></i>Â¡Alerta!</h4>' +
    '  Los cursos en vivo solo estÃ¡n disponibles para usuarios premium' +
    '</div>'
  );
})
```

I already checked that jQuery is included before everything else, also tried putting it inside a `$(document).ready(function() {}`

Comment: Do you get any error in browser js console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're including the javascript file in your `application.js` manifest:

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery
.. A bunch of other requires
//= require name_of_js_file
```

This would load a file named `app/assets/javascripts/name_of_js_file.js`. As a sanity check make sure `name_of_js_file.js` is loaded by checking your dev tools console. You can also add a `console.log` to fire when the script gets loaded as a sanity check.

Also, to be safe I'd always wrap this sort of code in a `$(document).ready(function() {}` callback, like you mentioned. The reason for this is that even if jQuery is loaded your `$('.disabled-course')` element may not even exist on the page yet.

Comment: I tried placing it inside `$(document).ready(function() {}` and requiring it in application.js and it's still not working. I'm using `require tree .` at the end of my application.js anyway

Comment: I went back to change something else and it was working. I think the `$(document).ready(function() {}` did it. Maybe the file hadn't refreshed or something weird...